# Group by age groups in mongo db

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using following mongo db query . and it is showing me only age groups of my personas data.

```
    db.amplifyindex.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$demographic" },
    { $match : { 'demographic.is_latest':"active",        
    'demographic.date_of_birth' : { $exists : true} } },
    { $project : {"ageInMillis" : {$subtract : [new Date(),   
    "$demographic.date_of_birth"] } } }, 
    { $project : {"age" : {$divide : ["$ageInMillis", 31558464000] }}},
    { $project : {"age" : {$subtract : ["$age", {$mod : ["$age",1]}]}}},

     ])
```

The result object  by this query is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58a42cbbdb5d880c1e000029"),
"age" : 29.0
 }
```

I want to get data in a way as :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58a42cbbdb5d880c1e000029"),
"age" : 10-30
"personas" : 10
}
```

Complete data structure in my scenario is given as :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58a42cbbdb5d880c1e000029"),
"persona_email" : "milton.ullrich@gmail.com",
"company_id" : "1",
"date_added" : ISODate("2017-02-15T10:23:15.000Z"),
"demographic" : [ 
    {
        "persona_fname" : "Hayden",
        "middle_name" : "Jacobs",
        "persona_lname" : "Schmeler",
        "gender" : "male",
        "date_of_birth" : ISODate("1987-06-16T19:00:00.000Z"),
        "marital_status" : "single",
        "height" : "2.1 feet",
        "weight" : "5 kg",
        "measurement" : {
            "waist" : "34 inch"
        },
        "disabilities" : "No",
        "race" : "Asian",
        "nationality" : "Jordan",
        "life_cycle" : "empty nest",
        "children" : {
            "gender" : "female",
            "date_of_birth" : ISODate("1987-06-16T19:00:00.000Z")
        },
        "medicare_no" : "4916725587565",
        "driving_licence_no" : "PACBALM420M",
        "id_no" : "4485872783336",
        "passport_no" : "OCRFHCNR",
        "residential_address" : {
            "unit_no" : 603,
            "street_no" : "34863 Ondricka Viaduct Apt. 154",
            "street_name" : "84799 Little Wall",
            "suburb" : "West Virginia",
            "postal_code" : "23873",
            "state" : "Dominica",
            "country" : "Cook Islands"
        },
        "work_address" : {
            "unit_no" : "6011865161287875",
            "street_no" : "630 Beer Underpass Suite 372",
            "street_name" : "87672 Lind Burg",
            "suburb" : "West Virginia",
            "postal_code" : "84356-3662",
            "state" : "Qatar",
            "country" : "British Indian Ocean Territory (Chagos Archipelago)"
        },
        "shipping_address" : {
            "unit_no" : "6011865161287875",
            "street_no" : "8292 Langosh Drive Suite 065",
            "street_name" : "9844 Nicolas Mount",
            "suburb" : "West Virginia",
            "postal_code" : "07014",
            "state" : "Togo",
            "country" : "Tunisia"
        },
        "job_title" : "Geoscientists",
        "employer_name" : "Aufderhar Group",
        "income" : 72577,
        "phone_numbers" : {
            "work_phone" : "993-783-7499",
            "home_phone" : "701.546.7016",
            "mobile" : "1-346-729-4392"
        },
        "emails" : {
            "work_emails" : "nikolaus.asa@gmail.com",
            "personal_emails" : "emmitt68@gmail.com"
        },
        "languages" : "italian",
        "data_source" : "soldi",
        "date_added" : ISODate("2017-02-15T10:23:15.000Z"),
        "source" : "soldi",
        "is_latest" : "inactive"
    },
    {
        "persona_fname" : "Julien",
        "middle_name" : "Hirthe",
        "persona_lname" : "Schaefer",
        "gender" : "female",
        "date_of_birth" : ISODate("1987-06-16T19:00:00.000Z"),
        "marital_status" : "single",
        "height" : "2.1 feet",
        "weight" : "5 kg",
        "measurement" : {
            "waist" : "34 inch"
        },
        "disabilities" : "No",
        "race" : "Asian",
        "nationality" : "Sudan",
        "life_cycle" : "single",
        "children" : {
            "gender" : "female",
            "date_of_birth" : ISODate("1987-06-16T19:00:00.000Z")
        },
        "medicare_no" : "4024007131689860",
        "driving_licence_no" : "OGOSUOIFSDN",
        "id_no" : "5523297913341227",
        "passport_no" : "WWZYTE489ZR",
        "residential_address" : {
            "unit_no" : 603,
            "street_no" : "338 Mueller Gardens Suite 397",
            "street_name" : "6302 Catalina Isle",
            "suburb" : "West Virginia",
            "postal_code" : "97534",
            "state" : "Antarctica (the territory South of 60 deg S)",
            "country" : "Turks and Caicos Islands"
        },
        "work_address" : {
            "unit_no" : "6011865161287875",
            "street_no" : "8561 Jesus Ridges Apt. 662",
            "street_name" : "1869 Josiah Wall Apt. 347",
            "suburb" : "West Virginia",
            "postal_code" : "14810",
            "state" : "Zambia",
            "country" : "Mongolia"
        },
        "shipping_address" : {
            "unit_no" : "6011865161287875",
            "street_no" : "514 Heller Center",
            "street_name" : "835 Paxton Cliffs Suite 040",
            "suburb" : "West Virginia",
            "postal_code" : "48942-3845",
            "state" : "Palau",
            "country" : "Belize"
        },
        "job_title" : "Geoscientists",
        "employer_name" : "Aufderhar Group",
        "income" : 72577,
        "phone_numbers" : {
            "work_phone" : "(553) 892-7614 x573",
            "home_phone" : "796.308.3001 x88799",
            "mobile" : "+1-876-339-1755"
        },
        "emails" : {
            "work_emails" : "prohaska.katelynn@hotmail.com",
            "personal_emails" : "ozulauf@jenkins.com"
        },
        "languages" : "german",
        "data_source" : "soldi",
        "date_added" : ISODate("2017-02-15T10:23:15.000Z"),
        "source" : "soldi",
        "is_latest" : "active"
    }
]
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within your group pipeline, create the age ranges as part of the `_id` key and this can be done through the use of the **[`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)** and **[`"$cond"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operators. Consider running the following pipeline to get the desired result:

```
db.amplifyindex.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$demographic" },
    { "$match": { "demographic.is_latest": "active" } },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "age": {
                "$divide": [
                    {
                        "$subtract": [
                            new Date(),
                            { "$ifNull": ["$demographic.date_of_birth", new Date()] }
                        ]
                    },
                    1000 * 86400 * 365
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$concat": [
                    { "$cond": [ { "$lte": [ "$age", 0 ] }, "Unknown", ""] },
                    { "$cond": [ { "$and": [ { "$gt":  ["$age", 0 ] }, { "$lt": ["$age", 10] } ]}, "Under 10", ""] },
                    { "$cond": [ { "$and": [ { "$gte": ["$age", 10] }, { "$lt": ["$age", 31] } ]}, "10 - 30", ""] },
                    { "$cond": [ { "$and": [ { "$gte": ["$age", 31] }, { "$lt": ["$age", 51] } ]}, "31 - 50", ""] },
                    { "$cond": [ { "$and": [ { "$gte": ["$age", 51] }, { "$lt": ["$age", 71] } ]}, "51 - 70", ""] },
                    { "$cond": [ { "$gte": [ "$age", 71 ] }, "Over 70", ""] }
                ]
            },
            "personas": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "age": "$_id", "personas": 1 } }
 ])
```

---

In the above pipeline, I've taken out the query for null date fields and replaced it with the **[`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#exp._S_ifNull)** operator within the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline. This will return the current date where the birthday field is null and thus yields an age of 0 years which will fall into a special age range bracket, thus the need to include all the documents, including the ones where the date of birth field missing.

In the case where the **[`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)** operator is used for all **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** expressions, the combination is crucial as it acts as a case statement where otherwise there will be nested **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operators.

To understand this design, take the third **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** expression

```
{ 
   "$cond": [ 
       { 
           "$and": [ 
               { "$gte": ["$age", 10] }, 
               { "$lt": ["$age", 31] } 
           ]
       }, 
       "10 - 30", // matching if
       ""  // else
   ] 
},
```

which essentially expresses the logic

```
if ( "$age" >= 10 && "$age" < 31 ) { return "10 - 30"; }
else return "";
```

**[`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)** is useful when used with the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operators as the expression will return an empty value except the matching one, which in turn will return the age group.

For example, an age of 30.645411 would return

```
"$concat": [ "", "", "10 - 30", "", "", "" ]
```

which then gives you an `_id` with value of `"10 - 30".`

Comment: Thank you very much. perfect help. @chridam

Comment: Also you could improve your query by using [buckets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) and its boundaries

Comment: @chridam, I am getting some extra group value by  " ". Could you please help me with the same.

Comment: Hi, what if my date is not ISODate? Its only "2021-06-06" format